# Adding "include:_spf.google.com" to my SPF record - would that authorize all gmail users?

Tags: email, gmail, spf

I have a domain and I want to use Gmail to send mail from it.
[The instructions for this](https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1092/How+do+I+set+up+my+email+using+Gmail%3F#spf) are: Add "include:_spf.google.com" to your SPF record.
My question is: wouldn't that enable every Gmail user in the world to send mail on behalf of my domain and pass the SPF test?
I must be missing something here.
[Google also give similar instructions.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will enable any gmail.com users to send emails in your name, because your SPF policy will explicitly authorize Gmail outbound mail servers to send emails in the name of your domain.

Comment: Thanks, PeterK. Now the technical side is clear, but I don't understand the logic: how is possible that BigCommerce and Google are instructing domain owners to authorize all the Gmail users in the world?

Comment: @user3450353: Indeed, in a shared resource scenario like this you are indirectly delegating some trust to other actors using the same hosts. However, Gmail/Google also supports [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail), which relies on PKI to validate email authenticity. DKIM does not have this trust issue, because you are not sharing your private key with anyone. Although DKIM alone is limited in scope (e.g. a bad actor can just skip signing the forged emails), [DMARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) lets you extend this scope.

Comment: @user3450353: So the short answer to your question: SPF is just one approach to protect your domain reputation and it has its shortcomings. DKIM is another approach with its own shortcomings, but using the two combined gives your very strong control over authorizing email sending in your name.

Comment: Thanks again. I think there's another thing I wasn't taking into account:

Comment: I think there's another thing I wasn't taking into account: when I open a hosting account and get a mail server, I am free to programmatically put whatever I want in an outgoing email's "From" field. I can impersonate to be sending from any domain I want. On the other, if I open a Gmail account, Google wouldn't let me impersonate, right? I don't have control over the "From" field. I guess only a Google employee would be able to put my domain in the 'From' field of a message, send it from a Google mail server, and exploit the "include:_spf.google.com" in my SPF record.

Comment: Mmm, does gmail.com do that for SMTP submissions (i.e. emails sent via smtp.gmail.com, instead of the web interface), too? In any case, SPF works on the transport level and doesn't concern itself with the From: field of the email header; it just doesn't make any statement about the contents of that field.